# How to manipulate date object of array before showing in on html page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am fetching data from server in json format in `.ts` file using below code:

```
this.displayList = this._myservice.myservice(this.taskdesc).subscribe(data => {
  this.dataa = data;
        this.ENTDT = data.map( e => e.ENTDT );
        console.log(this.ENTDT);
        // answer in console is 2-DEC-2017 03:22:11
       // need to change its format before rendering in HTML
```

displaying on `home.html` page using below code:

```
  <ion-list no-lines *ngFor="let list of displayList;let i=index;" >
    <ion-item>
{{list.TASKDESC}}
{{list.ENTUSR }}
{{list.ENTDT }}</ion-item>
```

The format of ENTDT in array is `22-DEC-2017 03:22:11` but I want to change it to `Date2 = new Date('22-DEC-2017 03:22:11').toISOString();` and then render on HTML.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can do this directly in HTML like this `{{ list.ENTDT.toISOString() }}`

Answer (score 0):

Just use map operator in your service and transform your result. We use map operator or rxjs in scenario where we want transform emitted value from observable.
Use this link for more information https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html.

Hope it will help.

Comment: so in simple language you mean to say, when i get a value in array, use rxjs, manipulate one of its object as needed and rest of the array will be unchanged, use the new arrayon html, am i getting it right ?

Answer (score 0):

First you could simply do this:

```
this.ENTDT = data.map( e => new Date(e.ENTDT).toISOString());
```

but you could should also be able to  use your current result and apply the date pipe to it in your html

https://angular.io/guide/pipes
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: may be i am not able  explain where i am stuck. I am unable to understand where in `.ts` shall i code what you guided so that `this.displaylist's entdt object is changed and i get the altered one `...or i need to code in html, please guide

Comment: If you just want to have a rendered date in your view you should go with the `|date` pipe

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
this._myservice.myservice(this.taskdesc).subscribe(data => {

var newdata = data.map(function(obj){

  var a = {};

  a.TASKDESC = obj.TASKDESC;
  a.ENTUSR = obj.ENTUSR;
  a.ENTDT = new Date(obj.ENTDT).toISOString()

  return a;

});


this.displayList = newdata;


})
```

Comment: what is b  ? i'll try and get back

Comment: a.TASKDESC is giving error `property TASKDESC does not exist on type '{}'..`  , please advise

Comment: can you post your json response ?

Comment: copied json response from `postman` , pastebin link - https://pastebin.com/14rAZG1x

Comment: just change var a = <any>{};